# Creating an affine or other type of projection from GCPs and convert to proj4 string

Tags: geospatial, proj

I was wondering how tools like http://www.georeferencer.com was made and if it would be possible to take a set of GCPs, create the transformation matrix and convert that into a proj4 string such it can be used as a projection for ol3 to show a static image ontop of a mail in the same way they are doing it.